# How to iterate and load property file values in UI using ZK?

Tags: java, zk

I have a property file named "ABC.properties" having values such as

```
A="APPLE"
B="BALL"
C="CAT"
```

Now i need to get these values and load in my UI. Have iterate and then need to load because like wise there may be more than 50 values in that property file.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: what do u mean by **''load in my UI''** ?

Answer (score 1):

In your zk.xml file, give the path of properties file you wanted to read.

```
<zk>
<system-config>
    <label-location>/path/to/ABC.properties</label-location>
</system-config>
</zk>
```

If you want to read them in zul file, for example you want to show label having value as A then

```
< label value="${labels.A}" />
```

If you want to read properties file's value in listener class then do

```
Labels.getLabel("A");
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know if there are more items in the property file then you need to fetch.
**Note :** Multiple properties files all readed in this way and are accessible in the same map.
If yes :

Convert the key's with subsections :

```
FRUIT.APPLE = apple
FRUIT.ORANGE = orange
TOYS.BALL = ball
TOYS.DOLL = doll
```

and so on.
The next thing is as @BhushanPatil already mentioned :

> In your zk.xml file, give the path of properties file you wanted to read.

```
<zk>
    <system-config>
        <label-location>/path/to/ABC.properties</label-location>
   </system-config>
</zk>
```

Then you have the following method `getSegmentedLabels` under [Labels](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.3/zk/org/zkoss/util/resource/Labels.html#getSegmentedLabels()).
This is the method we will use.

So if you want to declare it only in the zul, the next step is what you have to do :

```
<?xel-method 
    prefix="prop" name="all" class="org.zkoss.util.resource.Labels"
    signature="java.util.Map getSegmentedLabels()"?>

<vlayout forEach="${prop:all().get('FRUIT')}">
    <label value="${each.key} : ${each.value}"/>
</vlayout>
```

The [Xel-method](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Processing_Instructions/xel-method) is for declaring the static method (only way to acces a static method before ZK 8).
Now we want to get all our `FRUIT` labels, so we call the `getSegmentedLabels` with the Xel-method name `all()`.
This return a `Map<String,Object>` where all the labels are in.
We are interested only in the subsection `FRUIT` so we get the value behind the key `FRUIT`.
This object is again a `Map<String,Object>` wich contains every key under the `FRUIT`.
In this example it contains <'APPLE','apple'>,<'ORANGE','orange'>.

The next thing we need to do is iterating over the `Map` and showing all the values of the `Map`.

This we do with the `forEach` [attribute.](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/Iterative_Evaluation)
So the `each` object's value is now an Object of class `Entry<String,Object>`.
The only thing to show it now is showing the value, with is `Entry.getValue()`.